# Migrating from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, cinnamon, mate

currently I am using ubuntu 14.04 on Dell latitude 3550 i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz, 16 gb ram, 500gb hdd.

I use it mainly for programming, using Intellij ulitmate 14.1.7. The system hangs up a lot and I face problems in intellij like popup box are blank/transparent which is an open bug on intellij since last two years.

I want to know since ubuntu 16.04 is out now, which version of linux should I use, Ubuntu 16.04 (unity)/mate or linuxmint 17.3 cinnamon/mate. I want to get maximum performance so that intellij don't freeze a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used intellij but all I can say is, Ubuntu 16.04 runs good. I also use it for development purpose and everything works fine here.

Comment: Which version do you use unity or mate? What the config of your system?

Comment: Unity. and now I have updated it to Ubuntu 16.10